# Rundeck: Unable to curl rundeck api with jobIdFilter query option

Tags: curl, rundeck

I am unable to get the desired output for the below curl with **jobIdFilter** query option

**Desired Output**: Running execution list for the particular job id using **jobIdFilter** query option as per the document

"https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html#listing-running-executions"

**Actual Output**: Getting all the running executions on all the jobs and not for the specific mentioned job.

Curl: **GET /api/14/project/[PROJECT]/executions/running**

I have tried following ways.

`curl -s -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "X-RunDeck-Auth-Token:<token>" https://<rundeck-url>/api/14/project/pomt/executions/running -d jobIdFilter='0gad9b68f-e428-4df66-55ed-21f935551c18'`

`curl -s -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "X-RunDeck-Auth-Token:<token>" https://<rundeck-url>/api/14/project/pomt/executions/running?jobIdFilter='0gad9b68f-e428-4df66-55ed-21f935551c18'`

**Questions:**

1. Am I using the right approach to use **jobIdFilter**?
2. Is there a difference between **jobIdFilter** and **UUID**?

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the API version, the `JobIdFilter` option needs API 32 as a minimum version (you're using the API 14).
2. The single quotes on the job id aren't necessary.
3. The `JobIdFilter` is the Job UUID value needed in that endpoint option (in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) format basically).
4. I leave a working example script (using cURL) to get that info, take a look:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# protocol
protocol="http"

# basic rundeck info
rdeck_host="localhost"
rdeck_port="4440"
rdeck_api="38"
rdeck_token="IyEmTQQwXvJT4WtSVSBl1MO9pNPl8F7e"

# project/job
rdeck_project="ProjectEXAMPLE"
rdeck_job="28c901f4-873b-4303-83ff-1373d7fe3cfa"

# api call
curl -s --location --request GET "$protocol://$rdeck_host:$rdeck_port/api/$rdeck_api/project/$rdeck_project/executions/running?jobIdFilter=$rdeck_job" \
  --header "Accept: application/json" \
  --header "X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: $rdeck_token" \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json"
```

The job definition:

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: 28c901f4-873b-4303-83ff-1373d7fe3cfa
  loglevel: INFO
  name: HelloWorld
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - exec: sleep 30; whoami
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 28c901f4-873b-4303-83ff-1373d7fe3cfa
```

The result (adding [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) command to "beautify" the output):

```json
{
  "paging": {
    "count": 1,
    "total": 1,
    "offset": 0,
    "max": 20
  },
  "executions": [
    {
      "id": 5,
      "href": "http://localhost:4440/api/38/execution/5",
      "permalink": "http://localhost:4440/project/ProjectEXAMPLE/execution/show/5",
      "status": "running",
      "project": "ProjectEXAMPLE",
      "executionType": "user",
      "user": "admin",
      "date-started": {
        "unixtime": 1628021760315,
        "date": "2021-08-03T20:16:00Z"
      },
      "job": {
        "id": "28c901f4-873b-4303-83ff-1373d7fe3cfa",
        "averageDuration": 15708,
        "name": "HelloWorld",
        "group": "",
        "project": "ProjectEXAMPLE",
        "description": "",
        "href": "http://localhost:4440/api/38/job/28c901f4-873b-4303-83ff-1373d7fe3cfa",
        "permalink": "http://localhost:4440/project/ProjectEXAMPLE/job/show/28c901f4-873b-4303-83ff-1373d7fe3cfa"
      },
      "description": "sleep 30; whoami",
      "argstring": null,
      "serverUUID": "7062d7b6-c0d5-41d2-8e47-57e2b34eb581"
    }
  ]
}
```